# Legendre symbol (39/p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

$$\left(\frac{39}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{13}{p}\right)$$

$$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) is\;easy: $$

$$\begin{align} \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & \mathbf{if} \quad p \equiv 1 \pmod {12} \quad \mathbf{or} \quad p \equiv 11 \pmod {12}\\ -1 & \mathbf{if} \quad p \equiv 5 \pmod {12} \quad \mathbf{or} \quad p \equiv 7 \pmod {12}\\ \end{Bmatrix} \end{align}$$

$$And\;what\;about\;\left(\frac{13}{p}\right)\;?$$

Help please

Comment: Can you use quadratic reciprocity to reduce to $\left(\frac{p}{13}\right)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_criterion) to calculate a Legendre Symbol:

$$\left(\frac ap\right)=\left(a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\mod p\right)\in\{-1,0,1\}$$

Therefore, we have $$\left(\frac {13}p\right)=\left(13^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\mod p\right)$$

Does this help in any way?

Comment: I can calculate the individual values ( p=3 => 13/p=1,  p=5 => 13/p=(-1) ...) ​​but I can not understand how to unite them as in the example (13 / p)

Comment: Can you help me with this problem @lioness99a ?

Comment: @Vladislav I don't think so, sorry :/

Comment: $$ \begin{align} (2/p) = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & p \equiv 1 \pmod {8} \quad \mathbf{or} \quad p \equiv 7 \pmod {8}\\ -1 & p \equiv 3 \pmod {8} \quad \mathbf{or} \quad p \equiv 5 \pmod {8}\\ \end{Bmatrix} \end{align} $$

For example, where does (mod 8) come from here?
Or, in the case of (p / 3) - (mod 12)
@lioness99a

Comment: @Vladislav The $\bmod 12$ is probably seen most easily by using quadratic reciprocity.  Then you're looking at $(-1/p)(p/3)$.  You can easily find congruence conditions on the $(-1/p)$ and $(p/3)$ and combine them together using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.